# ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException despite adding within the capacity of the list

Tags: java

I have following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1, 555);
}
```

and it is initialize with 10 elements but i am getting exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0   
   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:612)  
   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:426)   
   at ListTest.main(ListTest.java:9)
```

while below code working fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0, 555);
}
```

Why can someone explain me ? and How to fix the issue i want to put item in 1th,2nd or 5th position in my code ?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: the size of an ArrayList is equal to current number of elements in it. So you can not put an element at position 1 into an ArrayList of size 0.

Comment: You're dealing with two different concepts: `size` and `capacity`. When you create a new `ArrayList`, the default length of its backing array (*capacity*) is `10`. But its initial *size* is `0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> it is initialize with 10 elements

No, it isn't. It's initialized with an internal *buffer* size of 10, but that's largely an implementation detail. The *size* of the list is still 0, as you can confirm by printing out `list.size()` before your `add` call.

It's important to differentiate between "amount of space in the buffer ready to accept more elements without copying" and "the size of the list". From the [`add` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-):

> Throws:
>   `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `index` is out of range (`index < 0 || index > size()`)

Here `size()` is 0, and `1 > 0`, hence the exception.

You should *always* check the documentation before assuming that it's the framework (or compiler) that's wrong.

> How to fix the issue i want to put item in 1th,2nd or 5th position in my code?

You *either* need to add enough elements first, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(null);
}
list.set(1, 555);
list.set(2, 500);
list.set(5, 200);
```

Note that these are *set* operations, not *add* - it's not clear whether you really want to insert or modify.

*Or* you should potentially use an array instead. For example:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
array[1] = 555;
array[2] = 500;
array[5] = 200;
```

In both cases, it's important to understand that indexes are 0-based - so `list.set(1, 555)` changes the *second* element of the list. You'd want `list.set(0, 555)` to change the *first* element. The same applies for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your answer : 
The code snippet of `public void add(int index, E element) {`

```
 if (index > size || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);
```

basically, when you do `new ArrayList()` the size of the list will be `0`. Since your *index* is *greater* than `size`, you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Ok but even in this case if i want to add element in some nth position what i have to do for this?

Comment: @subodh - *Jon Skeet* has written a really big answer for that :). You have to ensure that the size of list is atleast equal to the index which you are accessing.

Comment: @subodh imagine a piece of paper on which you wrote the numbers 0-9. this is your capacity. you can list 10 elements on this paper. but if you want to add an element, you MUST place it on the lowest free index. if there is no element, this index = 0. this is how an arraylist works. so you have to put 2 elements in the list to be able to get the element at index 1. else there is no element at index 1 and you will get out of bounds if you try to access it. got it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add elements to a list gradually, the list will be extended automatically.

If you want to add a certain element on a specific position, and you know the length of the amount of items you want; you can use an Integer array and convert that to a list afterwards, for example

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Integer []fixedLengthArray = new Integer[5];
    fixedLengthArray[1] = 3;
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(fixedLengthArray);
    for(int i= 0;i<intList.size();i++)System.out.println("Value of index "+i+":"+intList.get(i));
}
```

Output will be:

Value of index 0:null
Value of index 1:3
Value of index 2:null
Value of index 3:null
Value of index 4:null

Answer (score 0):

While the method is called `add` it is really an insert operation. You are essentially telling Java 'put this after the first item in the list' and Java is replying 'there is no first item in the list'.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all it will give a compilation error on

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

for `ArrayList<Integer>()`

`and it is initialize with 10 elements` Where you did that.?

What we see, It's not initialized with 10 elements actually its empty that why when you try to add something on index `1` it's giving IndexOutOfBound on line

```
list.add(0, 555);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(1);
     list.add(0, 555);
}
```

This code will help. This add method with index can be invoke if there is data in that index position.

Answer (score 0):

Because, at the second code piece zero is the first index. But at the first code piece one is not the first index and there isn't any memory allocation for your index.

You have to do like that;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
             List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
             list.add(0, 555); //Correct
             list.add(1, 55); //Correct
             list.add(2, 525); //Correct
             list.add(5, 55235); // Not-correct  ! 
        }
```

**or**

Create a list and assign all indexes with a default value. Then use the index which you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
             List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
             for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
             {
                 list.add(null);//or default value like -99
              }
             list.add(0, 555); //Correct
             list.add(1, 55); //Correct
             list.add(2, 525); //Correct
             list.add(5, 55235); //correct  ! 
        }
```

**or**

Just do that

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you will not get **fruits** from the tree untill you **plant** the Tree as simple as that .

When you initialised the list , it is an empty list , which can be verified by `list.size()` which will return `0` , Now you have 0 elements in the list and you are trying to access the 1 index , So it is giving you the exception

**From Java Docs**

```
void add(int index,
       E element)
```

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list(optional operation). Shifts the **element** currently at that position **(if any)** and any subsequent elements to the **right** (adds one to their indices).

and it `Throws:`

[IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) - **if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())**

Answer (score 0):

Your 'list' is still an ArrayList
So you can not change its index (Normally, index of an arraylist must be started at 0). So that the reason why when you put " list.add(1,555) " it throw an error.

Just simple `list.add(555)`

Instead of ArrayList you can use Map, SortedMap, HashMap, TreeMap. Those will store values as a pair Key - Value.

```
Hashtable<Integer,Integer> list = new Hashtable<>();
list.put(1, 555);

HashMap<Integer,Integer> list2 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
list2.put(3, 555);
```

Hope this help!